# What's the best way of handling begin and end times for an event in c# where the events are global

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone, globalization

We're making an app which is going to list events across the globe. The events span multiple days.

We want to store the begin and end of the event.

Should I just use 2 DateTime properties and store it all as UTC?

Should we just store the 2 points in time as ticks?

Should we be using a TimeSpan?

Would NodaTime be good here?

Comment: I would personally make each pair a tuple of time in ticks. I think that would be best for doing comparisons and then it's convenient to convert to DateTime for display. If you're checking the timespan frequently you could make the difference between item one and two a third item in the tuple.

Comment: Could you expand on that? I'm not offay with tuples :)

Comment: The close vote was probably because someone was confused by your "events are global" description. Two UTC DateTimes vs two long ticks from epoch are essentially the same.  A TimeSpan represents a length of time, not a point in time so that wouldn't work.

Comment: Store where? And what do you do with those events after you store them?

Comment: we're using ravendb - it's an mvc app

Comment: @iwayneo adding an answer with code.

Comment: To help make sure you handle time zones correctly, use Noda time.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would store everything as UTC time. Since .NET naturally supports converting dates to and from UTC, you don't have to worry about future compatibility. Most databases support storing dates in UTC format. I would also use TimeSpan for code readability when calculating time periods,but storing the datetime as ticks may give you a small performance benefit since you can do comparisons without creating DateTime objects. Depends on how many comparisons you do.

Answer (score 0):

Two datetimes as UTC at rest.  Then it will make sense to do operations when you have a start and no end since the event is underway at present.  WCF will even automatically make them local times across the wire for you if you like (be sure to set the DateTime.Kind).

DateTimes are ticks internally, so storing them as ticks accomplishes little.  They'll be ticks at rest in your DB.

Answer (score 0):

```
Tuple TimeSpan <long, long, long>;
TimeSpan myTimeSpan = new TimeSpan<start, end, difference>;
```

You use dot notation to access items like;
    long start = myTimeSpan.item1;
The Nth item would be accessed by; myTimeSpan.itemN;

From here if you need UTC time you can easily get it by doing something like;
    DateTime startingUTC = new DateTime(myTimeSpan.item1, UTC);

This constructer; public DateTime(long ticks, DateTimeKind kind) will allow you to easily produce DateTime objects in UTC or local time when you need to display the data to the user. Otherwise, it's much easier and more efficient to work with ticks.